# Having problems setting a key binding in Emacs "general.el" pacakage

Tags: emacs

I am using this https://github.com/noctuid/general.el to set my various key bindings. Here is a demonstration of a problem I am having:

```lisp
(general-nmap haskell-mode-map "<leader>t" 'foo-bar)
(general-nmap "<leader>td" 'my-rg-todo)
```

The second line causes the following error:

```
error: Key sequence <leader> t d starts with non-prefix key <leader> t
```

Why is the problem and what can be done?

Comment: This sounds specialized enough to be better posted to the package maintainer as a support issue. Perhaps notice also that we have a separate sibling site for [emacs.se] questions.

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68328/general-el-error-key-sequence-starts-with-non-prefix-key

Comment: "This sounds specialized enough to be better posted to the package maintainer as a support issue." - well, it's not a bug, so I don't wanna open an issue in GitHub.

Comment: "Perhaps notice also that we have a separate sibling site for Emacs questions." - Yea, I am aware of it. But it feels, that here I am getting more responses to Emacs questions.